# Minimal cell structures of relative CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I learned from Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology Section 4.C that we can know the mininal cell structure of a simply connected CW complex from its homology groups. The theorem is as follows:

> Proposition 4C.1. Given a simply-connected CW complex $X$ and a decomposition of each of its homology groups $H_n(X)$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups with specified generators, then there is a CW complex Z and a cellular homotopy equivalence $f:Z\to X$ such that each of $Z$ is either:

> (a) a 'generator' $n$-cell $e_{\alpha}^n$, which is a cycle in cellular homology mapped by $f$ to a cellular cycle representing the specified generator $\alpha$ of one of the cyclic summands of $H_n(X)$; or

> (b) a 'relator' $(n+1)$-cell $e_{\alpha}^{n+1}$, with cellular boundary equal to a multiple of the generator $n$-cell $e_{\alpha}^n$, in the case that $\alpha$ has finite order.

I wonder if there is a similar result for relative CW complexes?

Comment: This is rather vague. Can you state the precise theorem that you are talking about?

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for the comment. I have added Section 4.C in my question now.

Comment: That was not what I suggested. Your potential answerers are unlikely to have this book at their fingertips, so they are quite likely to just skip over your question. To avoid this, state the full theorem itself in your post. You might wish to review our guidelines for [formatiing and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post.

Comment: Now the theorem is added.@LeeMosher

Comment: Morally speaking, the relative homology of two pairs $(X, A)$ and $(Y,B)$ is isomorphic if $X \setminus A \simeq Y \setminus B$, so you shouldn't be able to recover much (if anything) about the cell structure on the subspace.